# Joomla 3.0 Register user with php script

Tags: joomla

I've searched and found a way to do this with JUser but when I try the script it says an include file can't be found and it doesn't exist on the server. I don't know if this is different for Joomla 3.0 so I was asking for help. Here's the script I tried:

```
<?php
   define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
   define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );
   define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
   /* Required Files */
   require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
   require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

   $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
   $app->initialise();
   require_once JPATH_ROOT.DS.'components'.DS.'com_users'.DS.'models'.DS.'registration.php';
   require_once JPATH_ROOT.DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'application'.DS.'component'.DS.'helper.php';
   $model = new UsersModelRegistration();
   jimport('joomla.mail.helper');
   jimport('joomla.user.helper');

   $username = 'jimporttest';
   $name = 'J Port2';
   $email = 'test @ mail.com';
   $password = 'test';
   $data = array( 'username' => $username,
             'name' => $name,
             'email1' => $email,
             'password1' => $password, // First password field
             'password2' => $password, // Confirm password field
             'block' => 0 );
   echo $model->register($data);
?>
```

Comment: Just need a few more pieces of info before you can get a good answer. First is, what version of Joomla are you using? Second, where are you running this script from? Is it in the cli folder? Or do you have it in the Joomla root (next to the configuration.php and the index.php). Those two things will get you a better answer.

Comment: It's Joomla 3.0, and the script is in the Joomla root folder.  I only put it there because that's where I read that it said to put it.

Answer (score 4):

you have to use the JPATH_BASE in the require_once clause (you are using JPATH_BASE_ROOT which is not defined).
Also in JOOMLA 3.0 the helper.php it is not in that position.

Try this code:

```
<?php
         define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
         define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );
         define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
         /* Required Files */
         require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
         require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

         $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
         $app->initialise();
         require_once(JPATH_BASE.DS.'components'.DS.'com_users'.DS.'models'.DS.'registration.php';
        //not necessary
        //require_once(JPATH_BASE.DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'application'.DS.'component'.DS.'helper.php';
         $model = new UsersModelRegistration();
         jimport('joomla.mail.helper');
         jimport('joomla.user.helper');

         $username = 'jimporttest';
         $name = 'J Port2';
         $email = 'test @ mail.com';
         $password = 'test';
         $data = array( 'username' => $username,
         'name' => $name,
         'email1' => $email,
         'password1' => $password, // First password field
         'password2' => $password, // Confirm password field
         'block' => 0 );
          echo $model->register($data);
  ?>
```

I've tried that in my joomla 3.0 installation and it works.

Andrea

Comment: It works! I have only one problem, the 0 value to 'block' is probably overwrite with the joomla value because into the users db it is ever to one and the email's body notification is only 'COM_USERS_EMAIL_REGISTERED_WITH_ACTIVATION_BODY'. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: I had the COM_USERS_EMAIL etc issue when I set this up to run from the admin side.  I discovered you need to specifically load the site language file.  $language = JFactory::getLanguage();
$language->load('com_users', JPATH_SITE, 'en-GB', true);  Which makes the problem go away - hope this helps someone else avoid several hours of Google searching :)

Answer (score 0):

here is the code you can use.

```
$data['name'] = $fname . ' ' . $lname;
$data['username'] = $email;
$data['email1'] = $email;
$data['email2'] = $email;
$pwd = substr(md5($email . $fname . time()), 0, 6);
$data['password1'] = $pwd;
$data['password2'] = $pwd;

JFactory::getLanguage()->load('com_users');
JModel::addIncludePath(JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_users/models');

$model = JModel::getInstance('Registration', 'UsersModel');
$return = $model->register($data);
```

Comment: How would I include the Joomla library files since this is an external script?

Answer (score 0):

For >=Joomla 3 we need to do use the following code instead. Changed from "JModel" to "JModelLegacy". [Click here](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2#General_changes) to view in detail.

```
$data['name'] = $fname . ' ' . $lname;
$data['username'] = $email;
$data['email1'] = $email;
$data['email2'] = $email;
$pwd = substr(md5($email . $fname . time()), 0, 6);
$data['password1'] = $pwd;
$data['password2'] = $pwd;

JFactory::getLanguage()->load('com_users');
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_users/models');

$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Registration', 'UsersModel');
$return = $model->register($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless your file is in the root folder where the Joomla system is installed, this error is definitely expected.

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

returns the working files path. Therefore you may need to modify the path accordingly. Use

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );
  echo JPATH_BASE;
```

to make sure the 'include' folder in the same path as JPATH_BASE retuns. For instance, if your file is in the 'www/example/test' folder, then use

```
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'../../'));
```

to get the correct base path.

Also I found some errors in your codes. Use this working codes for the testing purposes.

```
            <?php
                define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
                define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'../../'));
                define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

                require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
                require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

                $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
                $app->initialise();   

                require_once  JPATH_ROOT.DS.'components'.DS.'com_users'.DS.'models'.DS.'registration.php';
                $model = new UsersModelRegistration();
                jimport('joomla.mail.helper');
                jimport('joomla.user.helper');


                $username = 'ben';
                $name = 'ben';
                $email = 'test@mail.com';
                $password = 'test';
                $data = array( 'username' => $username,
                         'name' => $name,
                         'email1' => $email,
                         'password1' => $password, // First password field
                         'password2' => $password, // Confirm password field
                         'block' => 0 );

                $return = $model->register($data);
            ?>
```

'../../' part of the

```
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'../../'));
```

depends on the deviation of root folder as I explained earlier.